# Dictionary list how to compare probability and class type

Tags: python, json, list

Simple python question but I still cant seem to get it right.

```
ints = [{'intent': 'goodbyes', 'probablility': '0.43079117'}, {'intent': 'compliments', 'probablility': '0.3078408'}]

#how do i check that intent = goodbyes AND probability is > than 0.5
```

Comment: `[entry for entry in ints if entry['intent'] == 'goodbyes'] and float(entry['probability']) > 0.5]`

Comment: What should be the result? The elements for which the condition holds? Whether the condition holds for any or all elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def check_intent(ints):
    for i in ints:
        if i['intent'] == 'goodbyes' and i['probablility'] > 0.5:
            return True
    return False
```